# ZF2 get another navigation in global.php

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, navigation, zend-framework2

This is my navigation in global.php

```
'navigation' => array(
            'default' => array(
                    'loja' => array(
                            'label' => 'Loja',
                            'route' => 'loja',
                            'params' => array('action'=>'index'),
                            'pages' => array(
                                    'estoque' => array(
                                            'label' => 'Estoque',
                                            'params' => array('action'=>'index'),
                                            'action'=>'index',
                                            'id' => 'estoque',
                                            'route' => 'estoque',
                                    )),
                    ),
               'suport'=> array(
                    'test' => array(
                            'label' => 'Loja',
                            'route' => 'loja',
                            'params' => array('action'=>'index'),
                            'pages' => array(
                                    'estoque' => array(
                                            'label' => 'Estoque',
                                            'params' => array('action'=>'index'),
                                            'action'=>'index',
                                            'id' => 'estoque',
                                            'route' => 'estoque',
                                    )),
                    ),),
```

when I call navigation the 'default' comes, I want to call the navigation 'suport', how I can do it?
My code in layout.phtml ..

```
echo $this->navigation('Navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav dropdown-submenu')->renderMenu();
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own navigation factory by extending `Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultFactory`

```
namespace Application\Navigation\Service;

use Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory;

class MyNavigation extends DefaultNavigationFactory
{
    public function getName() {
        return 'suport';
    }
}
```

and in Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'my_navigation' => 'Application\Navigation\Service\MyNavigation'
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use your navigation `echo $this->navigation('my_navigation')->menu()`

Answer (score 0):

First create a container:

```
    <?php $container = $this->navigation()->findOneByLabel('support');?>
```

Read more about finding nodes here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.containers.html

Than use it:

```
    <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($container);?>
```

(Put this in your view script.)

Read more about this in the docs: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.menu.html

Answer (score 0):

Can You Try This in view script:

Create Container Like this

```
<?php $container = $this->navigation('support')->getContainer(); ?>
```

Echo the Container to use this one:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation($container); ?>
```